# React Native - What's the different about this.state.data with this.data?

Tags: react-native, react-state-management

I was confused what's the different about `this.state.data` with `this.data`

let say I have a code like this:

```
componentWillMount(){
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.list);
    api.get('my API Url')
    .then((response)=> {
      this.setState({data: JSON.parse(response.data)[0]})
      this.data=JSON.parse(response.data)[0]
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log("axios catching error")
      Alert.alert("failed", "Retry to retrieve from API", [{text:'OK', onPress:()=>{this.componentWillMount()}}])
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

constructor(props){
    super(props); 
    this.state ={ data:[] }
    this.data=[]
  }

class Visit extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.data.length==0){
      return(
        <Loader/>
      )
    }
    return (
      <Text>Visit</Text>
    );
  }
}
export default Visit;
```

with above code, I can't render `<Text>Visit</Text>` when `this.data` already have an array, but with `this.state.data` my App can rendering `<Text>Visit</Text>`,

so I want to know the different about `this.state.data` with `this.data`,

anyone can explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state.data` refers to `data` property of the current class `state`, while `this.data` refers to `data` property of current class.

A component's **State** is a trivial part of React environment, and if you can't understand this difference I suggest you to check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html).

I also suggest you to check [react official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), almost everything from React applies to React Native, for me, React Native is almost the same as React, the only difference is you have more limited components in RN. We could say that RN is a subset of React

Note: property or properties it's not the same than component's `props` defined in React specs

Comment: so the simple way is `this.state.data` can re-render the screen, while `this.data` can't do that? does it mean's `this.data` is like a `props` rather than a `state`?

Comment: Exactly, any modification to the component's `state` will fire it's `render ` method. And nope, also any modification of component's props will fire it's `render ` method. Assume that `this.data` is just a dummy var

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of React, it would be best to make use of the state. `this.state.data` refers to the `data` prop stored in the current component state. You can set the value by calling the `setState` method. On the other end, `this.data` refers to the `data` prop of the current class. You could change its value like you would other class variables in Javascript.